# Python dictionary is not being created as it should, it's being overwritten

Tags: python

I have the following code, my goal is to scrape a website and then create a dictionary with the results.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlparse, Request

attr = {}
def get_data():
    global attr
    page = 0

    attr_numbers_parent = []
    attr_dates_parent = []
    while page < 2:

        LOTTO_TYPES = ['mega-millions','powerball']
        BASE_URL = ('https://nylottery.ny.gov')
        BASE_URL_END = ('past-winning-numbers')
        PAGE = ('?page={}'.format(page))
        for lotto in LOTTO_TYPES:
            attr_numbers = []
            attr_dates = []
            fullpath = '{}/{}/{}{}'.format(BASE_URL,lotto,BASE_URL_END,PAGE)
            r = Request(fullpath, headers={'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
            html = urlopen(r)
            soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')

            # get date
            attr_date = soup.find('div', {'view-content'}).find_all('p',{'class':'result-date'})
            for item in attr_date:
                attr_dates.append(item.get_text().strip())
            attr_dates_parent.append(attr_dates)

            # get numbers
            attr_number = soup.find('div',{'class':'view-content'}).find_all('span', {'class':'numbers'})
            for item in attr_number:
                attr_numbers.append(item.get_text().strip())
            attr_numbers_parent.append(attr_numbers)
        page += 1
    attr[lotto] = [{'dates':attr_dates_parent, 'numbers': attr_numbers_parent}]
    return attr

x = get_data()
print(x)
```

The code is returning the dictionary `attr` with only the 'powerball' key, the 'mega-millions' key is missing. Isn't it supposed to create two keys with the loop?

Am I missing something?

Comment: The only time you put anything into the dictionary is at the end: `attr[lotto] = ...`. That's not in a loop, so this code cannot put more than one thing into the dictionary.

Comment: when the dictionary is in the loop, the data gets duplicated @kaya3

Comment: Then fixing your code is not as simple as moving that line from one place to another. But it is straightforward to see that this code can't return a dictionary with two items (unless it already had one with a different key, given that it's `global`, which it shouldn't really be).

Comment: @gm_will the reason why "data gets duplicated" if you move the `attr[lotto] = XXX` line within the loop is that you keep on appending to the same `attr_numbers_parent` and `attr_dates_parent` lists.  There's a reason we ask for [mcve] when it comes to debugging - reducing the issue to the simplest code reproducing it helps understanding what's wrong. So here's your mcve: https://pastebin.com/neAB7Ubt - now try to fully understand the execution flow (tracing code execution with a few `print` or the step debugger might help) and fix it so it gives the expected result.

Comment: As a side note: "parallel lists" is an antipattern - instead of having a list of dates and a list of numbers, you should try to build a list of `(date, number)` tuples or `{date: xxx, number: yyy}` dicts.